# Find the sum of :- $2017(2017^{100}) + 2016(2017^{101} + 2017^{102} + ... + 2017^{2016})$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, summation, problem-solving

> Find the sum of :- $2017(2017^{100}) + 2016(2017^{101} + 2017^{102} + ... + 2017^{2016})$.

**What I Tried** :- I notice this is the same as :-
$$2017(2017^{100}) + 2016(\sum_{n=101}^{2016} {2017^n})$$
$$\rightarrow 2017^{101} + 2016(2017^{101}) + 2016(\sum_{n=101}^{2016} {2017^n})$$
$$\rightarrow 2017(2017^{101}) + 2016(\sum_{n=101}^{2016} {2017^n})$$

Now how will I proceed. I am most annoyed with this problem because it has got unusual summations and multiplied in different no. of times.

Can Anyone help?

Comment: Are the number of terms in the brackets determined by the number of times specified in the parentheses?

Comment: Why the Downvote ? If it is due to the question I posted like that, sorry but I cannot help . But downvoting for that reason is not likely either .

Comment: @AidenChow yes , it means $2017^{100}$ is being added $2017$ times .

Comment: This question seems right for me, i don't know why it has downvotes. Also, is a shame that downvoters don't comeback to see this good question and remove their negative vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

Using $2016=2017-1$ everywhere should suffice.

Comment: Ok I guess you are right . That works quite well